# Julia DataFrame first row of data is being used as column names

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia

I have csv files that don't have a header:

> 20150409,      15.47,      15.77,      15.07,      15.15,   31116

So when I make a data frame with the file the first row of data turns into the column names for the data frames.  I would like to know how to create the data frame with names for the columns already in place(date,close,high,low,open,volume), or at least how to insert a new row for names and bump the data down into the body of the data frame after creating it.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

#### SOLUTION

Thanks Ismael, I ended up using:

```
df = readtable(file,names=   [symbol("date"),symbol("close"),
    symbol("high"),symbol("low"),symbol("open"),symbol("volume")])
```

Comment: You can use: `[symbol(name) for name in ["date", "close", "high", "low", "open", "volume"]]` or `map(symbol, ["date", "close", "high", "low", "open", "volume"])` to create the list of symbol names instead of: `[symbol("date"),symbol("close"),symbol("high"),symbol("low"),symbol("open"),symbol("volume")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass the `header = false` keyword argument (which defaults to true) to the `DataFrames.readtable` function, ie:

http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/io.html#advanced-options-for-reading-csv-files

`df = readtable("data", header = false)`

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of DataFrames.jl, the best way of reading DataFrame from CSV file with a missing header row is

```
df = CSV.read("file.csv", DataFrame; header=[:col1, :col2, :col3])
```

When the column names are unknown, use `header=0`. For reference, [here is the list of the `CSV.read` kwargs](https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/reading.html#CSV.read).